# Warrants and avoiding jail

Tags: criminal-law

Is there a way to take care of a warrant without being arrested if there is an amount attached to the warrant for unpaid fine?

Comment: In all sincerity: I would be surprised if this question were answered with anything other than pay the fine online or have your counsel pay the fine.  Best to consult competent counsel and not rely on the internet

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the jurisdiction and a lot of other factors you haven't addressed. In the United States, though, there are many circumstances where one could pay the fine and then simply appear in court to ask for the warrant to be lifted.

The smart play, of course, is to hire a lawyer to handle it.